# Data first many to many for EF Core

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have a SQLite DB that I am trying to use with EF Core database first.
It has a table of users, and a table of groups that users can belong to, and it has a mapping table because users can belong to multiple groups.

```
-- holds users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT,
);
-- holds groups users can belong to
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS group (
  _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT,
);
-- holds user group membership
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map_group_user (
  group_id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  UNIQUE (group_id,user_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
  FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES group(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I scaffold this up I get a warning from `dotnet ef scaffold` that it could not identify a primary key for map_group_user and it does not generate a model, and neither the User nor Group model contains any reference to the other (expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an explicit primary key to the `map_group_user` bridge table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map_group_user (
    group_id INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (group_id,user_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
    FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES "group"(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user_id)
);
```

The logical primary key for the `map_group_user` table is the combination of `group_id` and `user_id`, each combination which should ideally appear only once.

By the way, please avoid naming your tables and columns using reserved SQL keywords, such as `group`.  I don't know if this was giving you an error, but I have placed `"group"` in double quotes to escape it.

Comment: oops. there was an attempt to simplify my internal table names.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Did my answer fix your problem?  Not sure what your comment actually is supposed to mean.

Comment: I used `group` in my re-written for SO. Its not like that in my actual code base.

Comment: Also, your fix works. I am just trying to figure out how to use the result.